# Merging two data structures with Ansible

Tags: merge, ansible, ansible-2.x

*Ansible v2.9.25*

I'm trying to merge two data structures with Ansible. I'm almost there but I'm not able to merge all data.

Let me explain:

I want to merge **main_roles** together with **default_roles**:

```
main_roles:
  - name: admin
    role_ref: admin
    subjects:
      - name: test
        kind: ServiceAccount
      - name: test2
        kind: ServiceAccount
  - name: edit
    role_ref: edit
    subjects:
      - name: test
        kind: ServiceAccount


default_roles:
  - name: edit
    role_ref: edit
    subjects:
      - name: merge_me
        kind: ServiceAccount
```

I'm successfully combining with the following task:

```
- name: "Setting var roles_managed"
  set_fact:
    roles_managed: "{{ roles_managed | default([]) + [ item | combine(default_roles|selectattr('name', 'match', item.name) |list)] }}"
  loop: "{{ main_roles }}"
```

Printing the var via loop.

```
- name: "print all roles"
  ansible.builtin.debug:
       msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ roles_managed }}"
```

```
ok: [] => (item={u'subjects': [{u'kind': u'ServiceAccount', u'name': u'test'}, {u'kind': u'ServiceAccount', u'name': u'test2'}], u'name': u'admin', u'role_ref': u'admin'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "admin", 
        "role_ref": "admin", 
        "subjects": [
            {
                "kind": "ServiceAccount", 
                "name": "test"
            }, 
            {
                "kind": "ServiceAccount", 
                "name": "test2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
ok: [] => (item={u'subjects': [{u'kind': u'ServiceAccount', u'name': u'merge_me'}], u'name': u'edit', u'role_ref': u'edit'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "name": "edit", 
        "role_ref": "edit", 
        "subjects": [
            {
                "kind": "ServiceAccount", 
                "name": "merge_me"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This results in a combine on the `item.name`. But I want the result to be also a merge of the subjects. So i would need a end result of `merge_me` and `test` (the `subjects` under `name:edit`):

```
  - name: edit
    role_ref: edit
    subjects:
      - name: merge_me
        kind: ServiceAccount
      - name: test
        kind: ServiceAccount
```

What I'm understanding Ansible is not merging recursively by default. So I would need to set `recursive=true` in the `combine` filter. See: [Combining hashes/dictionaries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries)

But I'm not able to set this successfully in my context.

When I try: `{{ roles_managed | default([]) + [ item | combine(default_role_bindings, recursive=true|selectattr('name', 'match', item.name) |list)] }}` for example I'm getting an `'bool' object is not iterable"` error code...

I've tried many variations and searched many other posts. But I'm still unsuccessfully after probably too many hours ;). Hoping someone has a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both *main_roles* and *default_roles* are lists. It's not possible to combine lists. Instead, it's possible to add them and [*groupby*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby) name. Then combine the dictionaries with the same name, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_roles: "{{ my_roles|d([]) + [item.1|combine(list_merge='append')] }}"
      loop: "{{ (main_roles + default_roles)|groupby('name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_roles:
  - name: admin
    role_ref: admin
    subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: test
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: test2
  - name: edit
    role_ref: edit
    subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: test
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: merge_me
```

Use [*list_merge='append'*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries), available since 2.10, to append the items of the lists.

---

Append the *subjects* on your own if the option *append* is not available in your version, e.g. the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_roles: "{{ my_roles|d([]) + [item.1.0|combine({'subjects':_subj})] }}"
      loop: "{{ (main_roles + default_roles)|groupby('name') }}"
      vars:
        _subj: "{{ item.1|map(attribute='subjects')|flatten }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your example! I'm getting an `{"msg": "'recursive' is the only valid keyword argument"}` in my environment. Looks like `list_merge=` is a Ansible 2.10+ thing? (i'm at 2.9 at the moment)

Comment: Do you see any solution prior to 2.10? I'm working on RHEL and Ansible 2.10 is not supported at the moment: https://access.redhat.com/articles/5392421

Comment: Truly awesome! Thanks for a 2.9 & 2.10 solution, I've learned a ton today about data manipulation & Ansible.